# Correctness of labelling and alignment

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image]

(1). The figure must be centred.
(2). The points `Z`, `X` and `Y` ought to be properly labelled. (Note that the points are faraway from where they should be.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \usepackage{color}

  \begin{document}
  \normalsize{\textbf{Theorem 1.24.} \textit{The bisectors of the angles of a triangle meet in a point which is equally distant from the sides.}}
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
 \tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
 \tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
 \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
 \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
 \tkzDefPoint(3,7){C}
 \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
 \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
 \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
 \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,C,B)\tkzGetPoint{Z}
 \tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -150pt](C,Z)
 \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](Z)
 \tkzDefLine[bisector](C,A,B)\tkzGetPoint{Y}
 \tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -280pt](A,Y)
 \tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](Y)
 \tkzDefLine[bisector](C,B,A)\tkzGetPoint{X}
 \tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -280pt](B,X)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](X)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the two bisectors ACB and ABC to extend far beyond from the sides of the triangle (as they are now) or should they just extend to the opposite side?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, of course! I did not bother you the first time. But if you could do it, I shall be so grateful to you.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I want to do the adjustments for the same figure.

Comment: I'm confused, should the bisectors extend far beyond the opposite sides or not?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, bisectors must be extended just as in the figure.

Comment: And, for example, should the label "Z" be at the intersection between the ACB bisector and the side AB or  should "Z" be placed at the end of the bisector?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Please label the point `P` for the intersection. 
Other points must be at the ends of the three bisectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already had an initial version, but according to comments, the intent was another. In any case, I decided to include here both versions:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDefPoint(3,7){C}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)

\tkzDrawBisector[dashed,draw=gray](C,B,A)
\tkzGetPoint{X}
\tkzLabelPoints[left](X)

\tkzDrawBisector(A,C,B)
\tkzGetPoint{Z}
\tkzLabelPoints[below](Z)

\tkzDrawBisector(C,A,B)
\tkzGetPoint{Y}
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](Y)

\tkzInterLL(A,Y)(C,Z) 
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzLabelPoints[left](P)

\tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -20pt](B,P)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\clip
  (-1,-3) rectangle (13,8);
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDefPoint(3,7){C}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)

\tkzDefLine[bisector](A,C,B)
\tkzGetPoint{Z}
\tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -150pt](C,Z)

\tkzDefLine[bisector](B,A,C)
\tkzGetPoint{Y}
\tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -320pt](A,Y)

\tkzDefLine[bisector](C,B,A)
\tkzGetPoint{X}
\tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -300pt](B,X)

\tkzInterLL(A,Y)(C,Z) 
\tkzGetPoint{P}
\tkzLabelPoints[left](P)

\tkzLabelLine[pos=0.65](C,Z){Z}
\tkzLabelLine[pos=0.40](B,X){X}
\tkzLabelLine[pos=0.50](A,Y){Y}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedine Perfect set up!  What I missed were `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]` and `\tkzLabelLine[pos=0.65]`