# Drawing the bisector of an angle as a dashed-line segment

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image]

(1). `AX`, the bisector of the angle C^{'}AC, must be a dashed-line segment.

(2). `C^{'}X` must be drawn, and that line must be a dashed-line, too.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usetkzobj{all}
 \usepackage{color}

 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(3,7){C}
\tkzDefPoint(10,4){C^{'}}

\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C^{'})

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C^{'})
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C^{'})
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)

\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](A,B)
\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=||](A,C^{'})
\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=||](A,C)

\tkzDefLine[bisector](C^{'},A,C)
\tkzGetPoint{X}
\tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -273pt](A,X)
\tkzLabelLine[pos=0.45](A,X){X}
\tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C^{'},X)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For (1), use `\tkzDrawSegment[add=0pt and -273pt,dashed](A,X)`.

Comment: @Sigur It did work perfectly.  Thank you very much!

Comment: For (2), the problem is the coordinate for `X`. Related solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228470/14757

Comment: @Sigur Did not work out. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the relevant lines:

```
\tkzDefLine[bisector](C^{'},A,C)
\tkzGetPoint{x}

\tkzInterLL(A,x)(C,B)
\tkzGetPoint{X}
```

Obtain the bisector of `C^{'}AC` and get its end point `x`; then find `X` as the intersection between `Ax` and `CB`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(12,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(3,7){C}
\tkzDefPoint(10,4){C^{'}}

\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C^{'})

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C^{'})
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C^{'})
\tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)

\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=|](A,B)
\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=||](A,C^{'})
\tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=0.5,mark=||](A,C)

\tkzDefLine[bisector](C^{'},A,C)
\tkzGetPoint{x}

\tkzInterLL(A,x)(C,B)
\tkzGetPoint{X}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](X)

\tkzDrawSegment[dashed](A,X)

\tkzDrawSegment[dashed](C^{'},X)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Utterly grateful for providing me an answer. I was struggling to come up with an answer for the whole evening.